# Are opinions not allowed on meta.SE?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-answers

Though there's no reason mentioned, the most probable one from my POV is *opinion-based*. Is that assumption correct?

[image]

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368569/273829 (for those who can see it)

Where can I find the guidelines, rules, terms of services, etc. these decisions are based on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: If you click on the link in the banner to the [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) answer it tells you the reasons.

Comment: In addition to not answering the **12 year old** question, there's something quite different from your setup and ours; in [Mobile or Desktop, Landscape or Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w1Pc.jpg) the webpage completely fills the available screen, without any gaps top or bottom.

Comment: That tension has been there since the *very* beginning of the web. It is nothing new.

Comment: @Rob I know that (page). There are 6 list items. To such we are used to say in my mother tongue: „_Schmeck's!_“, literally translated to: "_Taste it (yourself)!_". I don't know the according idiom in the English langauage (yet) but I think you understand what I, what this means.

Comment: @Rob It's not about top or bottom, it's about the white space _left and right_ (that's also what's the Q there is about). Now that Glorfindel removed the table formatting (I did that intentionally) from the screenshot there there are no borders around it and hence it's not that obvious at first sight.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I also know that. I watched it live and in color [then and since then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273829/gerold-broser?tab=profile). What's the point of an "argument" like „It's there for so long. It got its right to stilll be here by that (and be here for all future).“? If all the great characters of mankind would have thought like that in the past we still would live in caves. (A bit exaggerated of course.)

Comment: @Rob What's the point of emphasizing "**12 year old**" if Qs and As stay here "forever", i.e. for all future readers/seekers that stumble across/find it someday; even more if the issue still exists?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Second to top-supported comment there: „_Hmmm. Most of the heavy meta users seem to violate these on a regular basis. Perhaps you need to mention that you're allowed to violate these principles, but only if you mention waffles._“

Answer (score 21):

Opinions are allowed, but answers should [answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), even on Meta Stack Exchange. You merely state you agree with the feature request; the correct way to do that is by upvoting the question. If you have additional information which might help clarifying or implementing the feature request, you can consider posting a comment, but I fear this doesn't really qualify; IMHO it's just a rant (but a civil one, I'll admit). I agree with the six(!) users who chose to delete this <s>answer</s> post; please do not undelete it (that *is* possible because the deletion was done by regular users).

As for the deletion reason, this canned one from the review queues would fit:

> #### This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
>
> “This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question.”

Comment: Thank you for your response. I gave additional information in the form of a screenshot with 1920x1200 there but it's only being displayed in edit mode.

Comment: Ah, I see it now (and I've edited your post so that it shows now). Of course, the reviewers didn't see that either. Now, IMHO, the question does not *need* a screenshot, especially since including one means you have to scroll (more) to read the other answers. You could try posting the screenshot as a comment...

Comment: Re "_done by [six] regular users_" – Does that mean that I can create five further accounts at SE, power them up for a while and then I can delete answers (questions too?) that have an opinion different to mine in it or that I don't like for some other reason?

Comment: There's something else I know from the 19-hundreds, regarding ([exaggerated] scroling on) web pages: "If something isn't present on the first page it's probably not worth being presented at all."

Comment: @GeroldBroser you could indeed create 5 sock accounts and get them all to 20k reputation. Chances of you succeeding before anyone finds out they are all you (which isn't illegal in and on itself) , and finding out you had them interact in any way (two accounts voting the same post for example) are extremely slim. And then using all 6 of your accounts to delete a post whould surely get all your accounts suspended, and probably your 5 socks outrigjt deleted. So yeah if you have a year or two to spare please go ahead.

Comment: @Luuklag Suspending/banning accounts in such a case is what I expect from every collaborative site, once detected. Surely I'm not going to go ahead for this. Shortly after the 5 min edit period I realized that I could have added "– in theory –" somewhere in it (though you confirm that it's also possible in practice). I refrained from deleting the comment and re-posting it with that again since I thought that with a bit AGF that can be read out implicitely anyway.